# Make docker build fail if tests fail

Tags: node.js, docker, mocha.js

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:carbon

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm install gulp -g

COPY . .

run gulp build --build
run npm test

EXPOSE 80
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Tests are ran using `mocha --recursive`

build.sh

```
docker build -t my-app .
echo $?
```

How can I detect that one mocha test fails, thus `npm test` should not be ok, and neither `docker build`?

I may have missed something in here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`RUN` in a Dockerfile will fail if the exit code of the command is non-zero. If that happens, `docker build` will also fail with a non-zero exit code.

Your `npm test` script needs to return a non-zero exit code when the tests fail.

For reference, you can check the exit code like this:

```
$ npm test
$ echo $?
```

Comment: problem was mocha exiting with 0 even if there were failures.

Answer (score 6):

You may change line `run npm test` to `run npm test || exit 1`

Ran a quick test and confirmed build is failing. Here is a screen shot.

[image]

Comment: That would work if this was a shell script, but this is a Dockerfile. The build would already be failing if `npm test` was returning a failure code.

Comment: This worked in a dockerfile for me, to solve the opposite problem of needing docker build to continue regardless of test failures so that we can publish the test results

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend to follow some docker and node app best practices. You shouldn't build your app inside a container with npm install and run the tests inside. The build and test lifecycles can be run on a CI/CD server (e.g. TravisCI https://travis-ci.org/ or CircleCI https://circleci.com - both are free for public GitHub repositories). During your CI pipeline you can detect a failing built/test and the CI can be configured more easily to not build your image after a failure. Your bundeled app should be copied inside your docker container from an CI server and then you should only start your application inside the container.

Comment: yes, but in my case, node environment is not on the computer, only in the container.

Comment: With multi-layer docker builds, I think it's best to have the build inside docker for consistency, I realize this is kinda of a new feature, but this option can save you a great deal of problems of build inconsistency