# How to make docker build (& Docerfile) respect the node version I set in package.json?

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, dockerfile, package.json

Our Node.js project requires Node version 14 or higher, so I set that in the package.json

```
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14"
  }
```

But the Dockerfile (some other developer wrote it) did not respect that, it looks like these

```
FROM node:12-alpine3.14
COPY package*.json ./
ENV NODE_ENV production
# RUN npm install -g npm@latest
RUN npm install
...
```

`docker build` succeeded but `docker run` failed exactly because of node 12.

How can I make `docker build` respect the nodejs version I set in the package.json?

Please note that the problem is easily fixed by just update `FROM node:14-alpine3.14`. But that is not my question is about. For example, say in the future the project needs node16 and we update that in `package.json` but forget to update the Dockerfile, I need a way to make docker build failed for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

I think make `docker build` failed is probably the only way (refer to [Make docker build fail if tests fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47947747/make-docker-build-fail-if-tests-fail) too).

So I find 2 ways to do that.

A) By using `RUN yarn` instead of `RUN npm install` in the Dockerfile, so yarn will issue the error and `docker build` failed. Then by checking the failed message someone who builds the docker image will know the dockerfile needs to update.

```
#11 The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=14". Got "12.22.8"
#11 1.363 error Found incompatible module.
#11 1.364 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c yarn]: exit code: 1
```

B) Create a `.npmrc` and set `engine-strict=true` so `npm install` will fail. Check [How to specify/enforce a specific node.js version to use in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28409883/how-to-specify-enforce-a-specific-node-js-version-to-use-in-package-json)